# How to add the current item with the previous item in a list using python

Tags: python, numpy

How to add the current list item with the previous 1st list item using python.

```
>>> l = [4,2,1,3]
```

If I perform the below I get cumulative sum

```
>>> new_l = np.cumsum(l)
```

But I want to add the current list only with the previous 1st list, the desired output should be like this one.

```
>>> new_l
[4, 6, 3, 4]
```

Comment: so you want to add the first item at the last place? Please explain the step you doing from `new_l=[4,6,7,10]` (output of `np.cumsum`) to your output

Comment: @NicoAlbers He just wants to add the `i`th and `i-1`th element in the array

Comment: Yeah, I just understood, thx! See my answer for vectorized (numpy) approach :)

Comment: Thanks, I got desired output with your help. How to multiply two list with float type

Comment: please make a new question or search for them, but keep the old topic here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this in plain python using a simple for loop

```
a = [4, 2, 1, 3]
b = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    if i == 0:
        b.append(a[i])
    else:
        b.append(a[i] + a[i-1])

print(b)
```

**Output**

```
[4, 6, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Why in the world are people down voting this ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your answer from a stand point of "this code works". All the down votes came after your answer was the accepted answer. I believe people are down voting it because it was accepted and it doesn't use fancy python syntax like some of the other answers here, which would make your answer "not very pythonic". Yep, the dogma around this language is all too real unfortunately. The op probably understood your answer better than the other answers because they probably aren't that familiar with python. I didn't down vote, but some explanation from down voters would be nice.

Comment: I down voted this answer because this does not use numpy. @Nico's answer or Daniel's answer are much better and they should be on top.

Comment: This solution is appropriate. The question shows the op is just starting to learn the language (maybe programming). Solutions with advanced language constructs or even worse external packages while correct may (nay, will) not provide any enlightenment to the OP.

Comment: The question is tagged `numpy`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use plain python (you'd better go the vectorization approach, in most cases, numpy is more performant), you could use [np.roll](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html):

```
In[12]: np.roll(l, 1) + l
Out[12]: array([7, 6, 3, 4])
```

With that, you can simply achieve your result with two lines:

```
In [14]: new_l = np.roll(l, 1) + l
In [15]: new_l[0] = l[0]
In [16]: new_l
Out[16]: array([4, 6, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind sticking to plain python:

```
>>> [sum(l[max(i-1, 0):i+1]) for i in range(len(l))]
[4, 6, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

First item is as in `l` then iterate with zip.

```
l[:1] + [i+j for i, j in zip(l, l[1:])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using plain python code. Using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) to yield consecutive elements and using the first element of list unchanged

```
>>> l = [4,2,1,3]
>>> l[:1] + [i+j for i,j in zip(l,l[1:])]
>>> [4, 6, 3, 4]
```

Or another one using `map` and `lambda`

```
>>> l[:1] + list(map(lambda x,y: x+y, l, l[1:]))
>>> [4, 6, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple ways you can do this with `numpy`:

Use `np.cumsum`, subtract out the previous terms

```
l=[4,2,1,3]
c = np.cumsum(l)
c[2:] -= c[:-2]
c

Out: array([4, 6, 3, 4], dtype=int32)
```

Pad with `0` and do broadcast addition:

```
l = [4,2,1,3]
l_ = np.r_[0, l]
l_[1:] + l_[:-1]

Out: array([4, 6, 3, 4])
```

or do boradcast addition and then pad with the initial value

```
l = np.array([4,2,1,3])
np.r_[l[0], l[1:] + l[:-1]]

Out: array([4, 6, 3, 4])
```

All of these will be much faster for large datasets than doing list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

If you don't necessarily want to use numpy then you can use `zip`

```
new_list.append(old_list[0])              # append first value
for i, j in zip(old_list, old_list[1:]):  # iterate over each consecutive pair
    new_list.append(i + j)
```

and if you are working with large list, consider using

```
itertools.izip(old_list, old_list[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a vanilla Python implementation in one line:

```
l=[4,2,1,3]
new_l = [l[i] + l[i - 1] if i > 0 else l[i] for i in range(len(l))]
```